# Get HTML field array index with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I got a form like below:

```
<form action='' method='POST' id='form1'>
<p><input type='text' name='text1[]' value='' />&nbsp;<input type='text' name='text2[]' value='' /></p>
<p><input type='text' name='text1[]' value='' />&nbsp;<input type='text' name='text2[]' value='' /></p>
<p><input type='text' name='text1[]' value='' />&nbsp;<input type='text' name='text2[]' value='' /></p>
<p><input type='text' name='text1[]' value='' />&nbsp;<input type='text' name='text2[]' value='' /></p>
</form>
```

I want to use jQuery to do the following task: if any field in text1[] change, the such value shall be updated accordingly into the field text2[].
I did made searches but found nothing about how to use jQuery to get the index of the current item in the field array.

Could you please help?
Thanks

Comment: What for you searched then? Have you really searched index - http://api.jquery.com/index/ ?

Comment: show us what you have tried

Comment: look at sibling relationship... [.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)

Comment: how can I make up a vote for Vladimirs???

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

```js
$("input[name='text1[]']").keyup(function() {
  $(this).siblings("input[name='text2[]']").val(this.value);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action='' method='POST' id='form1'>
<p><input type='text' name='text1[]' value='' />&nbsp;<input type='text' name='text2[]' value='' /></p>
<p><input type='text' name='text1[]' value='' />&nbsp;<input type='text' name='text2[]' value='' /></p>
<p><input type='text' name='text1[]' value='' />&nbsp;<input type='text' name='text2[]' value='' /></p>
<p><input type='text' name='text1[]' value='' />&nbsp;<input type='text' name='text2[]' value='' /></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I dont want to use siblings, I don't want to get depended on the html form

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I got this worked like a charm

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#form1 input[name="text1[]"]').change(function() {
        var index = $('#form1 input[name="text1[]"]').index(this);
        $('#form1 input[name="text2[]"]:eq(' + index + ')').val("1");
    });
});
```

Don't know why it didn't work before I joined stackoverflow :D I remember I tried this before :D
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this better way

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#form1 input[name="text1[]"]').change(function() {
            var index = $('#form1 input[name="text1[]"]').index(this);
            $('#form1 input[name="text2[]"]').eq(index).val("1");
        });
    });
</script>
```